# Finding FreeImage.so

Tags: android, c, freeimage

Can any one tell me where can I find freeImage.so?I have been trying a lot to find the same and have not been succesfull..any help would be highly appreciated.I have tried to convert freeimage.a to freeImage.so and that also haven't worked yet.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: which extension is this .a and .so??

Comment: .a static file and .so shared file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile .so from FreeImage sources yourself. Just add `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY` into FreeImage's `Android.mk`. You will also need a correct header file to import functions from .so into your project.

P.S. Why don't you like static library .a?

Comment: Can you please specify where should I put the .a file and what Am I supposed to give in .mk file?I have been behind this for more than 100hrs

Comment: Put in into the folder where ``Android.mk`` our your main project reside and link it to your .so. Why don't you check out Linderdaum Engine and copy-paste configs from there? It links FreeImage statically on Android.

Comment: Can you provide a link to teh Linderandum engine? and is that an android project?

Comment: I am working on Ubuntu,the site says it is for windows..will that make a difference?

Comment: There is a .tar.gz package there. Just download it - there is a freeimage.a there.

Comment: Ok,one final thing...I think it works only from armeabi-v7a, shouldn't I include a seperate version of freeimage.a for armeabi processors?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14334/discussion-between-sreekanth-karumanaghat-and-sergey-k)